# How to reduce multiple buttons, for multiple same functions

Tags: javascript, html, duplicates, reduce

I work on little app for my students. On the page will be math example to solve and under the example is always button which after click shows you result if u were correct or not. This is code for first to examples to solve on the first line. Ofc i dont plan have only 2 examples but around 10-20. So id like to ask you if there is any option how to reduce duplication, make it smater, cleaver, cleaner. I use pure HTML/CSS/JS. I don't know if it is possible but i'd like to avoid have multiple hardcoded buttons with multiple examples on the 1 page.

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="example">
          $${{ - b \pm \sqrt {{b^2} - 4ac} } \over {2a}}$$
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="toggle" onClick="toggle()">
          Toggle
        </button>
        <div id="result" class="num-1">this is result</div>
      </div>
      <!--NEW EXAMPLE -->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="example">
          $${{ - b \pm \sqrt {{b^2} - 8ac} } \over {2a}}$$
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="toggle" onClick="toggle()">
          Toggle
        </button>
        <div id="result" class="num-2">this is result</div>
      </div>
```

```
<script>
    function toggle() {
      let x = document.getElementById("result");

      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Idk what to expect. In React i'd use .map function and in the and i'd fill up only diferent examples. Is it possible something "similar" in HTML/JS only?

Comment: I suggest to make it in only with JS in HTML instead of mix of JS, CSS, and HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be cleaner if you did it only using js as dudung recommended. But here's something else you can do, this answer is similar to Dhana D's, but it has the toggle functionality that you wanted. You can simply create arrays of object to store questions, answers and toggle states and Iterate through them and create "html string" and append to the container hardcoded in our html using innerHTML property.

Toggle functionality:
As you can see we're creating unique ids for result tags using index and we're also passing the same index while calling the toggle function, the toggle function uses the index "param" to form the id of the result tag and changes the result tag's display property.

```js
const examples = [
{
 que: "Question - 1",
 show: false,
 ans: "this is the result 1",
},
{
 que: "Question - 2",
 show: false,
 ans: "this is the result 2",
},
{
 que: "Question 3",
 show: false,
 ans: "this is the result 3",
}
]

const container = document.querySelector("#examples-container")

examples.forEach((ex, i) => {
    const example = 
  `<div class="card">
      <div class="example">
          ${ex.que}
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="toggle" onclick="toggle(${i})">
          Toggle
       </button>
       <div id="result_${i}" style="display:${ex.show? 'block': 'none'}" class="result">${ex.ans}</div>
      </div>
   </div>`
      container.innerHTML += example
})

function toggle(i) {
  const result = document.querySelector("#result_"+i)
  result.style.display = examples[i].show? "none": "block"
  examples[i].show = !examples[i].show
}
```

```html
<div id="examples-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've already started warking on something similar cuz i've realized that .map function in React is also in vanilla JS. Works well :) Would be is possible make it with .map pls? If yes how?

Comment: Cool, also, .map function isn't something related to React. It's just one of many methods of an Array object in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript, you can create a container and utilize `innerHTML`. For example:

```js
var cont = document.querySelector('.container');

cont.innerHTML = "";

arr = [4, 8, 16, 32, 64];

arr.forEach(e => {
  cont.innerHTML += `<div class="card">
        <div class="example">
          $$ - b \pm \sqrt {{b^2} - ${e}ac} } \over 2a$$
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="toggle" onClick="toggle()">
          Toggle
        </button>
        <div id="result" class="num-2">this is result</div>
      </div>`
});
```

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

What if you want to add element in the middle of existing elements hardcoded on HTML? You can use `insertAdjacentHTML`. Reference: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/javascript/javascript-append-html/